# Why <li> is displayed outside the container?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, overflow

My tags cloud is currently out of order, for e.g: the tag "Arfen Plus" and "Children's Coltalin" are not properly rendered.

How do I ensure the content in #dvTagCloudContent do NOT flow outside the container? How to make tags display like a normal paragraph ? THanks.

**How it look right now**:

[image: Result]

**HTML**:

```
<div id="dvTagCloudContent">
<ul id="ulTagCloud">                     
    <li class="TagCloudSmall"><a href="/drug/info/1">Arfen Plus</a></li>                                        
    <li class="TagCloudMedium"><a href="/drug/info/2">Biogesic</a></li>                                      
    <li class="TagCloudLarge"><a href="/drug/info/3">>Botox</a></li>                                             
    <li class="TagCloudLarge"><a href="/drug/info/4">>Brumed</a></li>                                            
    <li class="TagCloudMedium"><a href="/drug/info/5">>Children's Coltalin</a></li>                                      
    <li class="TagCloudMedium"><a href="/drug/info/6">Coldcap-A/Coldtab-2</a></li>                      
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#dvTagCloudContent {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 290px;
    line-height: 200%;
}
#ulTagCloud{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
#ulTagCloud li { display: inline;}  
.TagCloudSmall    { font-size: small;margin-right: 5px; color: #ccc !important;}
.TagCloudMedium  { font-size: medium;margin-right: 5px; }
.TagCloudLarge  { font-size: large;margin-right: 5px;font-weight: bold;}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML instead of the screenshot?

Comment: Is `#dvTagCloudContent` wider than _its_ parent container?

Comment: @j08691 I replaced the screenshot with HTML code :)

Comment: @Neps The #dvTagCloudContent is the container itself, it is the gray line that the tags flow over

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `display: inline` property under #ulTagCloud li. Remove it and replace it by `block` so each item will take a line. The ul should have a `display: inline-block` to make it fit to content.

Comment: For tag cloud, I cannot have each item in one line. So I tweak your answer a bit:

new CSS:

    #ulTagCloud li { display: inline-block;} /*it works*/

Answer (score 1):

Hi after trying for a while, I found 2 solutions:

Soln #1: Change the HTML to use [p] tag: (It works, content will break into new line, no more overflow.)

```
    <div id="dvTagCloudContent">
        <p id="pTagCloud">                     
           <a class="TagCloudSmall" href="/drug/info/1">Arfen Plus</a></li>                                        
            <a class="TagCloudMedium" href="/drug/info/2">Biogesic</a></li>                                      
            <a class="TagCloudLarge" href="/drug/info/3">>Botox</a></li>                                             
            <a class="TagCloudLarge" href="/drug/info/4">>Brumed</a></li>                                            
            <a class="TagCloudMedium" href="/drug/info/5">>Children's Coltalin</a></li>                                      
            <a class="TagCloudMedium" href="/drug/info/6">Coldcap-A/Coldtab-2</a></li>                      
        </p>
    </div>
```

Soln #2: Change li CSS to: **#ulTagCloud li { display: inline-block;}**. (Simple!)

All explained in this [**CSS article**](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/) .

The end result is just nice :

[image: The result]

Answer (score 0):

try display:block; width:auto; overflow:display;  for that container div. you can set min-width:300px or whatever you want